# GridView Timing Issue

Tags: asp.net

I have a problem with timing.  I have a GridView that I set the DataKeyName to the rows key value.  My problem is that one of the dropdownlist's in that row needs that key value.  How do I go about getting the correct key value into the SqlDataSource?  Right now it uses the default value so the dropdownlist is not populated.

Select statement -

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource4" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AuditDevConnectionString2 %>" 
     SelectCommand="sp_fc_vm_getSpokeTo" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
     <SelectParameters>
          <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GridView1" DefaultValue="-1" Name="DebtorKey" 
                PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
          </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to handle this by only using the dropdownlist when the row is in edit mode.